# Como crear campo acumulado en stored procedure de MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento en Mysql, el cual retorna el saldo anterior y los movimientos de venta y haberes de la cuenta de un cliente:

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `USP_Listado_sp_ctacte` (
    IN mes INT,
    año INT,
    idcliente INT,
    fecha date
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        acumulado DECIMAL (10, 2);


SET acumulado = 0;

(
    SELECT
        DATE_FORMAT(a.fecha, '%d/%m/%Y') AS fecha,
        "SALDO ANTERIOR" AS tipo,
        a.saldo AS debe,
        0 AS haber
    FROM
        tb_resumenes a
    WHERE
        (
            MONTH (a.fecha) = MONTH (fecha - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
            AND YEAR (a.fecha) = YEAR (fecha - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
            AND a.idcliente = idcliente COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
        )
)
UNION
    (
        SELECT
            DATE_FORMAT(
                a.fecha_crea,
                '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S'
            ) AS fecha,
            "VENTA" AS tipo,
            a.total_importe AS debe,
            0 AS haber
        FROM
            TB_ENC_SALIDA_PRODUCTOS a
        INNER JOIN TB_TIPOS_DOCUMENTOS_EMITIR b ON a.codigo_tde = b.codigo_tde
        WHERE
            a.estado = 1
        AND (
            MONTH (a.fecha_sp) = mes COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
            AND YEAR (a.fecha_sp) = año COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
            AND a.codigo_cl = idcliente COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
        )
        ORDER BY
            a.codigo_sp
    )
UNION
    (
        SELECT
            DATE_FORMAT(a.fecha, '%d/%m/%Y') AS fecha,
            a.tipo AS tipo,
            0 AS debe,
            a.monto AS haber
        FROM
            tb_pagos a
        WHERE
            (
                MONTH (a.fecha) = mes COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
                AND YEAR (a.fecha) = año COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
                AND a.idcliente = idcliente COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
            )
    );


END
```

el caso es que declare una variable y la setie en 0, pero como voy sumando si es un debe o restando si es un haber?

Comment: ¿De qué modo determinas si es *haber* o si es *debe* en tu código?

Comment: todo lo que esta registrado en tb_enc_salida_productos son ventas y aumentan la deuda...mientras que todo lo registrado en pagos son haberes.

Comment: O me convendria tener una sola tabla con todo? El objetivo es mostrarlo en un reporte rdlc en C#